# How to set different ingress root endpoint

Tags: questdb

I installed questDB to my AKS cluster using helm, but my ingress is looking to route that is different from "/". The questdb console is trying to get js/css files from wrong root path. How I can fix it? Has some EnvVar that I can set to change the root path from console app?

[image: no css and js files]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the asset_path must be defined into build ConsoleApp time. The helm installation just up a predefined build to root path. I solve it using a subdomain to avoid to change root path:
[image]